# Can we do query parallelization/ partitioning for a Azure Stream Analytics job which has multiple queries to multiple output types?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Understand from this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs), that Table Storage and Cosmos DB do support partitioning with ASA job.

However, does it work with, for example:

1. Single ASA job

   - Input: Event hub with 8 partitions
   - Outputs: Table Storage with 4 partitions and Cosmos DB with 4 partitions

Would the above work, as in able to harness the benefit of query parallelization/ partitioning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm double checking with engineering to get a definitive answer, but from my current understanding this job would not be fully parallel. The mapping in partitions needs to happen from input to output.

Comment: I was wrong, it's supported, full answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the scenario you have here is supported, but it's a bit more subtle than expected.

The key here is that both Table Storage and Cosmos DB are output that don't have set partition counts. With a job like yours, from a logical standpoint, ASA will actually run 8 partition writers for each output. It just happens that 4 of them will be running empty. Or rather, instead of 8 writing to 2 outputs each, you will have 8 with 4 writing to one output, and 4 writing to the other.

Note that if you were to target EH as an output, instead of Table or Cosmos, you would need that EH to have 8 partitions, even if you were only sending data to 4, to keep full parallelization.

In terms of query, you will need to write something like:

```
WITH inputStream AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [input]
)

SELECT * 
INTO [table]
FROM inputStream
WHERE PartitionKey IN (1,2,3,4)

SELECT * 
INTO [cosmos]
FROM inputSTream
WHERE PartitionKey IN (5,6,7,8)
```

Or any kind of query that doesn't break the partition alignment.